# Is the App.xaml.cs something that must complete before the application becomes ready to use?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

The application I am working on has this coded in the app.xaml.cs

```
    protected override async void OnStart()
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            cardSetWithWordCount = DB.GetCardSetWithWordCount(Settings.cc.Text());
            PointChecker.CheckPoints();
            StartTimer();
        });
    }
```

What I would like to have some advice on is if there's any reason to run code inside an OnStart inside a Task like this.  Also the OnStart an event or is it some part of the application start up that needs to complete before the application is usable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well OnStart is a method in the Xamarin.Forms App lifecycle. And is called as soon as your Xamarin.Forms execution is started.

The XF docs say:

> Application developers override this method to perform actions when the application starts.

As of to the other question you asked:

> the OnStart an event or is it some part of the application start up that needs to complete before the application is usable

It is a part of the Xamarin.Forms App lifecycle,

The XF docs say:

> The Application class contains three virtual methods that can be overridden to handle lifecycle methods:
>
> OnStart - Called when the application starts.
>
> OnSleep - Called each time the application goes to the background.
>
> OnResume - Called when the application is resumed, after being sent to the background.
>
> Note that there is no method for application termination. Under normal circumstances (i.e. not a crash) application termination will happen from the OnSleep state, without any additional notifications to your code.

The Task.Run there is used for a simple reason, that none of your lines of code inside the Task.Run can be awaited which means none of them are awaitable, a task by definition is for this very reason hence it is used. Understand how tasks work [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Good luck

Revert in case of queries